# On Error GoTo not working within a Do While loop

Tags: vba

[I have read through other questions and answers on this matter in other threads on this website however I have not found a solution that works for me yet]

Hi, I have written a macro in which excel loops through a bunch of tables, copies them and pastes them in bookmarks within a word document. I started noticing that I would occasionally (important to note - this only sometimes happens) run into errors when copying a range ("Run-Time Error '1004': CopyPicture method of Range Class Failed"), however simply pressing Run Macro (F5) would continue the macro without any issues.

I thought this may have something to do with excel not being able to keep up with all of the copying and pasting, so I added in an error handler that would wait 1 second when encountering that particular error, then resume. This actually worked exactly as intended, so I continued building up my code. **However, when encountering this error within a Do While loop, my code doesn't go to the ErrHandler. I just get the small Debug window**

My code is very long, so I have just included the relevant parts.

```
    Do While blockStart.row < endCell.row
        
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                'first instance of blockStart is set before this Do While loop
            Set blockEnd = blockStart.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)
            Set CopyBlock = Range(blockStart, blockEnd)
        
            bmHolder = bmHolder + 1 'used as an ID for bookmark destinations in word document
        
                'Application.CutCopyMode = False - i've played with this to see if it stops the error from occuring, but no luck
            CopyBlock.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture 'ERROR OCCURS HERE 
                'w is a variable for the word document
            w.Bookmarks("Block" & CStr(bmHolder)).Select
            w.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine
        
            Set blockStart = blockEnd.Offset(2, -2) 'next "block" always starts 2 down and 2 left from blockEnd
        On Error GoTo 0
            
    Loop
```

As you can see from the code above, I have included `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and `On Error GoTo 0` within the loop. I have tried to have this outside the loop however I am encountering the same issue.

Although I don't think it is relevant, my error handler code is below

```
Select Case Err.number
    Case 4198, 1004 
        errOccurred = errOccurred + 1
           
        If errOccurred > 5 Then
            Stop 'for debugging
        End If
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        
        Resume
End Select
```

From [this forum post](https://msgroups.net/excel.programming/copypicture-method-of-range-class-failed-us/33849) it seems that the fact that this error even occurs is a bug, but I don't know.

Am I doing something wrong, is there anything I can change to ensure that my code runs through the error handler when encountering an error?

Comment: You haven't actually posted the code where the `ErrHandler` label is used...

Comment: @dai The first block of code in my post has On Error GoTo ErrHandler within the Do While loop, and the second block of code in my post is the code below ErrHandler:. Ideally, when the error is encountered during the Do While loop, it would go down to the errHandler, wait 1 second, and try again (which works everywhere else in my code - i know it's not perfect but it works the way I want it too). However, in the Do While loop, it doesn't even go to the errHandler, it just stops and gives me the Debug window

Comment: @AnthonyGFS Not exactly a solution but If that error handler is only meant to capture `CopyPicture` then in my opinion you should have your `On Error` code to be limited to just that line and not the entire `Do While` loop. Currently you are trapping all sorts of error that could happen within the loop, not just error specific to `CopyPicture`

Comment: Also, you want `Case 4198, 1004` - Otherwise you are testing to see if `4198=True` or `1004=True` and obviously that never happens.

Comment: You are also missing a `Case Else` in the error handler, so if it's any error other than the ones you expect, it just gets ignored, so it continues on from that point, and the error is never reset/handled. If would also be helpful to show us that the error handler is located in the right place, instead of just showing us what it is.

Comment: @braX that's my fault for trying to reduce the amount of text in my post. There is a case else, however I just didn't include it. I am starting to think that what i am experiencing is a result of encountering the issue once, handling it properly (i.e application waits 1 second) then resumes. I have read that resuming code resets the error handler, so i believe i am just encountering that error AGAIN on the same line, and because it has resumed, the error handler has been reset and i am now getting the debug window. I am trying to test my way into that possibility now

Comment: @AnthonyGFS perhaps add a `Debug.Print` so that you can see in the immediate window if it went to the error handler before.

Comment: @brax Thanks for your comment about the Case, I have amended it now as per your comment. Again, that was me trying to compress my code down to something digestible for stack overflow, i did actually have two cases however it was coded poorly so i made some changes on the fly.

Comment: @RaymondWu I have added a debug.print line for catching how many times the error handler actually processes an error. But now that i am trying to force the error, it just doesn't seem to want to break!